# Opening gnome-terminal during preseeded 22.04 desktop installation

Tags: system-installation, gnome-terminal, preseed

I have a preseed configuration file for a 22.04 desktop install, and I'd like to open `gnome-terminal` during the installation - just before the pertitioning - to display a `whiptail` message box.

It seems that the ubiquity installer still utilizes the `d-i partman/early_command string` parameter, as I set a couple variables there, but as a test I've tried setting this to:

```
d-i partman/early_command string \
  DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal;
```

to see if I can at least get a terminal window to open, but I'm not able to get that working (tried without setting the DISPLAY variable as well).  I also tried putting this in a shell script on the CD image and then calling that instead, but still no dice.

Anyone able to provide some insight?  Thank you!

Comment: I just tried this myself in a virtual machine and it's working ok, are you sure the preseeding file is being used?

Comment: Hi @Baa , yes, I'm confident the preseed file is being read, as there are other preseed configurations that are being applied.

I attempted to clear the entire preseed file except for:
```
d-i partman/early_command string \
  gnome-terminal;
```

and it still didn't work.  Would you mind sharing the kernel options passed in GRUB?